# Cloning node and modifying the clone using xquery

Tags: xquery

I have some html stripped out of an online dictionary that I want to convert to XML for eventual conversion into a word list for a BK-tree. The online dictionary records variant spellings, but sometimes does so by putting a vowel or ending that may or may not appear in parenthesis, like so:

```
<td>
    <span class="FORM">
    <span class="HDORTH">a</span>
    <span class="POS"> indef. art. </span> Also 
    <span class="ORTH">an</span>. Early forms: as subj.,
    <span class="ORTH">ane</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">on</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">o</span>; as obj., 
    <span class="ORTH">ane</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">on(e</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">o</span>, &amp; (chiefly masc.) 
    <span class="ORTH">an(n)e</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">æn(n)e</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">en(n)e</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">en</span>; after prep.,chiefly 
    <span class="ORTH">ane</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">on(e</span>, masc. also 
    <span class="ORTH">anne</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">æn(n)e</span>, fem. also 
    <span class="ORTH">anre</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">are</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">hare</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">ore</span>; gen. 
    <span class="ORTH">anes</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">æn(n)es</span>, 
    <span class="ORTH">en(n)es</span>.</span>
</td>
```

I've written the following XQuery to convert the HTML TO XML, stripping anything that's not in tags and selecting elements based on the class of the particular span:

```
declare function local:node-change($nodes as node()*) as node()* {
  for $span in $nodes
  return 
    if ($span/@class = "HDORTH") then <headword>{$span/text()}</headword>
    else if ($span/@class = "POS") then <part_of_speech>{$span/text()}</part_of_speech>
    else if ($span/@class = "ORTH") then <variant>{$span/text()}</variant>
    else $span
 } ;

<list>
{
let $collection:=concat($collection, '?select=*.xml')
let $q:=collection($collection)

for $y in $q 
let $s := $y/td/span/*

let $c := local:node-change($s)
(:let $l := local:stripleftparen($c):)

order by number(substring(substring-before(tokenize(document-uri($y), "/")[last()],"."),4))
return
<entry ref="{number(substring(substring-before(tokenize(document-uri($y), "/")[last()],"."),4))}">{$c}</entry>
}
</list>
```

This returns the following XML:

```
<entry ref="3">
        <headword>a</headword>
        <part_of_speech> indef. art. </part_of_speech>
        <variant>an</variant>
        <variant>ane</variant>
        <variant>on</variant>
        <variant>o</variant>
        <variant>ane</variant>
        <variant>on(e</variant>
        <variant>o</variant>
        <variant>an(n)e</variant>
        <variant>æn(n)e</variant>
        <variant>en(n)e</variant>
        <variant>en</variant>
        <variant>ane</variant>
        <variant>on(e</variant>
        <variant>anne</variant>
        <variant>æn(n)e</variant>
        <variant>anre</variant>
        <variant>are</variant>
        <variant>hare</variant>
        <variant>ore</variant>
        <variant>anes</variant>
        <variant>æn(n)es</variant>
        <variant>en(n)es</variant>
    </entry>
```

What I need to do now is clone the nodes that have parens, so that I can modify the clone and have the following result, but I'm not sure how to do so.

```
<entry ref="3">
        <headword>a</headword>
        <part_of_speech> indef. art. </part_of_speech>
        <variant>an</variant>
        <variant>ane</variant>
        <variant>on</variant>
        <variant>o</variant>
        <variant>ane</variant>
        <variant>on</variant>
        <variant>one</variant>
        <variant>o</variant>
        <variant>ane</variant>
        <variant>anne</variant>
        <variant>æne</variant>
        <variant>ænne</variant>
        <variant>ene</variant>
        <variant>enne</variant>
        <variant>en</variant>
        <variant>ane</variant>
        <variant>on</variant>
        <variant>one</variant>
        <variant>anne</variant>
        <variant>æne</variant>
        <variant>ænne</variant>
        <variant>anre</variant>
        <variant>are</variant>
        <variant>hare</variant>
        <variant>ore</variant>
        <variant>anes</variant>
        <variant>ænes</variant>
        <variant>ænnes</variant>
        <variant>enes</variant>
        <variant>ennes</variant>
    </entry>
```

I know I need to use substring, substring-before, or substring-after to actually modify the node, but where I'm having problems is in the actual cloning process.  `Copy` doesn't work within the for/return loop, and everything I've found online either suggests that for copying nodes or talks about de-duplicating data (which I'll need to do, but I want to get it exactly as I want it before I do so).  How can I copy a node, modify the copy, and display the results so that I can get what I'm looking for?

Comment: If your query processor supports XQuery Update, things will be pretty easy (see http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#Non-Updating_Expressions for some more insight).

Comment: I saw that page, but the copy function does not appear to work within a for statement, as I mentioned.

Comment: What are the rules for stripping? It seems some have the paren and some do not.

Comment: The copy/transform expression is not part of the FLWOR expression, but you can bind the result of such an expression to a let, for or return clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear what the rules are. But it seems to me that you should be able to do it all at once in the node-change function.

I would think you could do something along these lines:

```
      declare function local:node-change($nodes as node()*) as node()* {
      for $span in $nodes
      let $varient1 :=
        if ($span/@class = "HDORTH") then <headword>{$span/text()}</headword>
        else if ($span/@class = "POS") then <part_of_speech>{$span/text()}</part_of_speech>
        else if ($span/@class = "ORTH" and contains($span/text(),')')) then <variant>{translate($span/text(),'()','')}</variant>
        else $span
        (:Implement some if here to get the other varient if needed :)
        let $varient2 := <varient/>
      return 
        ($varient1, $varient2)
     } ;
```

If there are three varients (not sure) just follow the same pattern. Of course, the else for any one of the addition varients could be empty element and you could strip that at the end (i.e. else <empty/> ) and then just strip any <empty/> in the result.

something like this maybe (guessing at the rules):

```
    xquery version "3.0";
    declare function local:node-change($nodes as node()*) as node()* {
      for $span in $nodes
      let $varient1 :=
        if ($span/@class = "HDORTH") then <headword>{$span/text()}</headword>
        else if ($span/@class = "POS") then <part_of_speech>{$span/text()}</part_of_speech>
        else if ($span/@class = "ORTH" and contains($span/text(),'(') and not(contains($span/text(),')'))) then <variant>{substring-before($span/text(),'(')}</variant>
        else if ($span/@class = "ORTH" and contains($span/text(),'(') and contains($span/text(),')')) then <variant>{concat(substring-before($span/text(),'('),substring-after($span/text(),')'))}</variant>
        else if ($span/@class = "ORTH" and not(contains($span/text(),'(')) and not(contains($span/text(),')'))) then <variant>{$span/text()}</variant>
        else $span
        let $varient2 := if ($span/@class = "ORTH" and contains($span/text(),'(') and not(contains($span/text(),')'))) then <variant>{translate($span/text(),'(','')}</variant>
        else <empty/>
        let $varient3 := if ($span/@class = "ORTH" and contains($span/text(),'(') and contains($span/text(),')')) then <variant>{translate($span/text(),'()','')}</variant>
        else <empty/>
      return 
        ($varient1, $varient2, $varient3)
     } ;
    let $cell := <td>
        <span class="FORM">
        <span class="HDORTH">a</span>
        <span class="POS"> indef. art. </span> Also 
        <span class="ORTH">an</span>. Early forms: as subj.,
        <span class="ORTH">ane</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">on</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">o</span>; as obj., 
        <span class="ORTH">ane</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">on(e</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">o</span>, &amp; (chiefly masc.) 
        <span class="ORTH">an(n)e</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">æn(n)e</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">en(n)e</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">en</span>; after prep.,chiefly 
        <span class="ORTH">ane</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">on(e</span>, masc. also 
        <span class="ORTH">anne</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">æn(n)e</span>, fem. also 
        <span class="ORTH">anre</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">are</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">hare</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">ore</span>; gen. 
        <span class="ORTH">anes</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">æn(n)es</span>, 
        <span class="ORTH">en(n)es</span>.</span>
    </td>

    let $s := $cell/span/*
    let $c := local:node-change($s)
    return
    $c[not(local-name()='empty')]
```

returns this:

```
<headword>a</headword>
<part_of_speech> indef. art. </part_of_speech>
<variant>an</variant>
<variant>ane</variant>
<variant>on</variant>
<variant>o</variant>
<variant>ane</variant>
<variant>on</variant>
<variant>one</variant>
<variant>o</variant>
<variant>ane</variant>
<variant>anne</variant>
<variant>æne</variant>
<variant>ænne</variant>
<variant>ene</variant>
<variant>enne</variant>
<variant>en</variant>
<variant>ane</variant>
<variant>on</variant>
<variant>one</variant>
<variant>anne</variant>
<variant>æne</variant>
<variant>ænne</variant>
<variant>anre</variant>
<variant>are</variant>
<variant>hare</variant>
<variant>ore</variant>
<variant>anes</variant>
<variant>ænes</variant>
<variant>ænnes</variant>
<variant>enes</variant>
<variant>ennes</variant>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Kevin.  The problem is that for the items with the parenthesis (either both with a letter or letters in between or a open-parend with letters following) I need to have both a version with the parenthesis stripped but the letter or letters remaining and a version with the parenthesis and everything either between them or after it gone.  Your suggestion about setting it up with two let statements seems really promising, though.  I didn't think about that.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: See edits to the answer, is this close? you could also extend to other varients

Comment: I think I missed one thing in that, which is if there is a ( and a ), get the letter in between also, but it is close

Comment: I just checked this and it works great.  I had to add a pass over with a function I have that removes empty elements to strip out the <emply\> elements, but that's not that big a deal.  Thanks so much for the help!